# Newbe asking / MySQL Update with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, post

I am new on the Platform and also new in Programming. So you need it to explain it to me on the easy way. Normally i Programm microchips and have nothing to do with DBs. ^^

---

I just du for myself a Homepage and try to do all by myself.
Now i try to Update my "Backend" Settings in the Database over a the "POST" Methode.

```
UPDATE controll SET ticket_new = $_POST["chagne_tickets_new"] WHERE language = $_POST["Change_language"]
```

Thats just e example how i want it but i have no idea how to do it.
i also tried it like that:

`$Change_ticket_post = $_POST["Change_tickets_new"]
$Change_language =    $_POST["Change_language"]`

`UPDATE controll SET ticket_new =". $Change_ticket_post. " WHERE language =". $Change_language;`

Also that doesn`t works and i got a FATAL ERROR also.

Comment: please show thew full code(and full error messages); i suspect it s how the variables are quoted, but its hard to tell without the full php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.

First of all, it's best practice to use `'` (single quotes) to wrap array keys.

So, you should do like this:

```
<?php
$Change_ticket_post = $_POST['Change_tickets_new'];
$Change_language =    $_POST['Change_language'];
```

Second, the values in a MySQL query should be wrapped within `'` (single quotes) too.

So, your query would be:

```
<?php
$query = "UPDATE controll SET ticket_new='$Change_ticket_post' WHERE language='$Change_language';
```

And most of all, you need to learn a lot.

Coding best practices:
http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/

http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

SQL Injection:
[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Sanitize & escape user data:
[What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

Comment: 1) single\double makes no difference, 2) only quote strings.

Comment: @Dagon I said it's best practice.

Comment: you are on a serious roll today with answers. Slow down and not burn out (and make em great) :p ... as you know or should know is that you just helped him to do 2nd level sql injection. And instead of just pointing to a thing, you should show him how to do it safely or discuss it.

Comment: Thanks for your exampel i found my mistake ;) Thanks also for the sites i am sure i can use them. Normally i go to w3schools and check it there or try it.

Comment: @Nopus w3schools is not updated and trustworthy. don't use it.

Comment: okey, any good ideas for php, SQL etc. (like w3school) exampel lists or should i look around here in the stack Forum?

Comment: For PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/ is the best resource one can have. You can also follow: www.sitepoint.com/php/